# What is the correct way to set autoCommit to true after downloading Postgres large object?

Tags: java, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL large object API to store binary files.
I need to implement a resource to download this file.
The download resource produces an 'application/octet-stream' response.
I see that, i should return 'auto commit' to 'true' after the download complete. If i set the 'auto commit' in 'finally' (as in the code below), the file is not being downloaded.

Do i need to implement some InputStream extension and only set 'auto commit' to 'true' when the stream is being closed?
What is the best approach to take here?

```
 try (Connection connection = Portal.getInstance().getConnectionProvider().getConnection())
    {
        try
        {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false); //large objects cannot be used in auto commit mode
            PGConnection pgConnection = connection.unwrap(PGConnection.class);
            LargeObjectManager largeObjectManager = pgConnection.getLargeObjectAPI();
            LargeObject largeObject = largeObjectManager.open(largeObjectId, LargeObjectManager.READ);           
            return largeObject.getInputStream();
        }
        finally
        {
            //connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just returning the input stream doesn't constitute downloading. You would have to complete the download, that is to say read the input stream to its end, and then set autocommit.

Comment: I understand that, the user that using this API completes the download. I need to know when it happened.

Comment: You could wrap the returned input stream and set autocommit when you read end of stream, or on close, whichever is appropriate.